# Error trying to insert a list of dictionaries with pyodbc and python in a database hosted in Azure

Tags: python, azure, pyodbc

I'm trying to insert a list of dictionaries with pyodbc and python but I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: ('Params must be in a list, tuple, or Row', 'HY000')
```

I have a database hosted in Azure and I need to insert 1800+ rows in a table like the following example

```
kp = {'documents': [
{'id': '1', 'keyPhrases': ['sport', 'baseball', 'aliens']},
{'id': '2', 'keyPhrases': ['play', 'capacity', 'tired']},
{'id': '3', 'keyPhrases': ['international', 'balance', 'boring']}
]

lst = []
for x in kp['documents']:
    for i in kp['keyPhrases']:
        lst.append({'keyphrases': i, 'paragraph_id': x['id']})
cursor.fast_executemany = True
sql = 'INSERT INTO keyphrases2 (keyphrases, paragraph_id) VALUES (% 
(keyphrases)s, %(paragraph_id)s'
cursor.executemany(sql, lst)
```

Comment: Your posted code fails to reach the first `append` due to a syntax error and a reference error.  The code isn't minimal: the code through the nested loop is functionally independent of the final 4 lines -- one or the other should be replaced by hard-coding.  You've left out the trace-back, an important part of the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pyodbc does not support named parameters; the question mark (`?`) is the only parameter placeholder we can use. Also, as indicated by the error

> Params must be in a list, tuple, or Row

the row data cannot be a `list` of `dict`, it must be either

- a `list` of `list`,
- a `list` of `tuple`, or
- a `list` of `Row` objects.

So you need to do

```python
kp = {'documents': [
{'id': '1', 'keyPhrases': ['sport', 'baseball', 'aliens']},
{'id': '2', 'keyPhrases': ['play', 'capacity', 'tired']},
{'id': '3', 'keyPhrases': ['international', 'balance', 'boring']}
]}

lst = []
for x in kp['documents']:
    for i in x['keyPhrases']:
        lst.append( (i, x['id']) )  # (keyphrases, paragraph_id)
cursor.fast_executemany = True
sql = "INSERT INTO keyphrases2 (keyphrases, paragraph_id) VALUES (?, ?)"
cursor.executemany(sql, lst)
```